# NPM installation

Tags: node.js, npm

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install npm@latest -g
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/

removed 182 packages, and changed 3 packages in 28s
```

I updated manually TLS 1.2, rebooted my PC and newly installed Node-v16.11.0 and npm 8.0.0.

I'm still getting this error while installing `npm install --save firebase`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the beginning of October, 2021 ([announcement](https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/)) the npm registry must use `https`, not plaintext `http`. To resolve the issue:

1. Check the registry of your npm: `npm config get registry`
2. If it shows any link starting with `http` only then you need to update the registry to use `https` secure TLS based version:

   ```
   npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
   ```

This will update `registry` and resolve your issue.

Comment: Try this but not working!

Comment: what is the error? show exact stack trace